# Is there an encyclopedia/list of common type classes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Is there any website that lists and describes common type classes in Haskell?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might find "The Typeclassopedia" by Brent Yorgey (published in [issue 13 of 'The Monad Reader'](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf)) helpful. From the abstract:

> The standard Haskell libraries feature
>   a number of type classes with
>   algebraic or  category-theoretic
>   underpinnings. Becoming a ﬂuent Haskell
>   hacker requires intimate familiarity
>   with them all, yet acquiring this
>   familiarity often involves combing 
>   through a mountain of tutorials, blog
>   posts, mailing list archives, and IRC
>   logs.  The goal of this article is to
>   serve as a starting point for the
>   student of Haskell  wishing to gain a
>   ﬁrm grasp of its standard type
>   classes. The essentials of each  type
>   class are introduced, with examples,
>   commentary, and extensive references
>   for  further reading.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: too bad pdfs don't support hyperlinking to sections, and google's html conversion doesn't show the diagrams..

Comment: Indeed.  I would have liked to open the "extensive references for further reading" in a new tab, without manually typing the URL into my browser.

HTML++

Comment: I just found an supposedly up-to-date online version in the haskell wiki:
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Traversable
(Although the references are not in a separate paragraph.)

Comment: Whoa, not what I was hoping for: that article doesn't include common type classes like `Eq`, `Ord`, and `Show`, instead claiming that the most "basic" and "ubiquitous" type class is... `Functor`?

Answer (score 3):

The Haskell 98 Report [lists the predefined types and classes](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html).

If there's a library type you're interested in, you might want to start at the Haskell Library [Contents](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/index.html) or [Index](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/doc-index.html).